# Highchart 4.1.5 not wotking with Grails 2.5.0

Tags: grails, highcharts

I am using Grails 2.5.0 with highchart 4.1.5 and jquery 1.11.1. I keep getting highchart is not defined. I know that Highchart is not supported with jquery 1.11.1 but i cannot downgrade my plugin nor can I go up to 2.x.
Anyone using Highchart with Grails 2.5.0?

Comment: It should work with jQuery v1.11.1. Make sure that Highcharts is loaded **after** jQuery. If this won't help, then simply follow [OPTION #2](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/installation) with standalone framework.

Comment: Yes, its loading after highchart js is loaded. But the problem now is the graphs are not proper. They are broken but work well with juery 1.7.2 and now i am using 1.11.1

Comment: It's hard to believe that 1.11.1 version of jQuery breaks Highcharts. Could you create jsFiddle with that issue? Maybe there is some rare case when it's broken?

Comment: Sorry for the trouble. But it works well, there were a few options which i had to set and everything works fine except the zoom feature